# python to javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone help me to fix this regex to use in javascript?

```
(?<!\\\\)#\\{{1,2}
```

Regex tester said:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:((?<!\\)#\{{1,2})|(.))/: Invalid group
```

Thanks.

Comment: javascript won't support lookbehinds.

Comment: can you help me remake it? i don't have any experience with regex :( it was for slim-template hightlighting in texmate. `'#embedded-ruby': [ { token: 'punctuation.section.embedded.ruby', regex: '(?<!\\\\)#\\{{1,2}'`

Comment: replace `(?<!\\)` with `(?:^|[^\\])`

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:((?:^|[^\])#\{{1,2})|(.))/: Unterminated character class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe `/(?:((?!\\)#\{{1,2})|(.))/`. in python `negative lookback` is `(?<!...)` but in javascript is `(?!...)` just remove `<`